# Can a Gnosis Safe Wallet be Owner of Another Gnosis Safe Wallet?

Tags: gnosis-safe

In a Gnosis Safe Wallet setup, can one of the keys be another gnosis safe multisig? Such that in 1/2 setup, the second multisig wallet is able to initiate transactions  on behalf of the first multisig

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question literally, then the answer is <s>Yes</s> **BUT** No ... *(seriously)*
You can add any address **as an owner**, even non-existent or contracts, but it will not work.

You need to log in with a wallet to approve and sign transactions using your private key.
Contracts don't have private keys. Gnosis Safe Wallet is a contract.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of accounts on Ethereum:

- Externally Owned Accounts (EOA): can initiate transactions
- Contract Account (CA): can contain logic

A Gnosis Safe Multisig is a smart contract and by design it does not have the ability to sign messages even if you setup your main safe with that secondary safe as an owner, so the answer to your question is **no**.

However you could adapt the Gnosis Safe Multisig for ERC-1271 and allow signatures on behalf of the secondary safe, but the contract account per se still can not sign messages itself.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts cannot produce cryptographic signatures without exposing the underlying keys to generate those signatures to all network participants, however ERC-1271 enables pseudo-signing of data by a smart contract.

The most recent Gnosis Safe contract has built in support for ERC-1271, so Safes can be signers for other safes.

See gnosis safe code here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol#L334-L347

Maybe earlier versions did not have this support, but the latest Safe version does.

You'll have to use wallet connect to propose these and sign from the multisig signer, but it is possible and does not require modifying existing code.

I've personally seen multiple projects have multisigs with signers being other multisigs.